# 5X5 UIButton selection logic

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I have a 25 buttons in my UIView in 5x5 format, I have set the button tags to 1 to 25, the numbers on the button title appears randomly between 1-25. What I'm trying is when a user has clicked 5 buttons in a single row, column or diagonal its selected color should change. My current logic is to check if the button tag in row,col or diagonal is selected through manual checking like `button.tag 1 & 2 & 3 & 4& 5` is selected then [`button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonselectedimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];` But I will have to manually write about 12 conditions for this. I was wondering if there is any quick formula to do this check.

Comment: I am facing the same problem now.Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Ya, I used the number divided by order logic, where the  quotient and remainder will get u the desired position but still i had to repeat the same loop for row,col and two diagonals but atleast i didnt had to write the 12+ conditions. I will add the answer with the function I used, u can go through it and see if it helps u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define ORDER 5 //declared at the beginning

-(void)flipButtonsVisibility:(UIButton*)sender {

    [sender setSelected:!sender.isSelected];
    [sender setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];


    NSLog(@"tag:%ld",(long)sender.tag);
    int x,y,x1,y1;
    BOOL row,col,diag1,diag2;
    row=FALSE;col=FALSE;diag1=FALSE;diag2=FALSE;
    x=(int)sender.tag/ORDER;
    y=sender.tag%ORDER;
    if (!y)
    {
        y=ORDER;
        x-=1;
    }
    x1=x;
    y1=y;

    NSString *log=@"";

    NSLog(@"x=%d,y=%d",x+1,y);


    //Loop to check if 5 buttons in row/col/diag are selected
    //For row check

    for (int i=ORDER*x+1; i<=ORDER*x+ORDER; i++)
    {
      log=[log stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,",i]];
        if (![[_buttons1_25 objectAtIndex:i-1] isSelected])
        {
            row=FALSE;
            break;
        }

        NSLog(@"%d==%d",i,ORDER*x+ORDER);
        if (i==ORDER*x+ORDER)
        {
            row=TRUE;
        }
    }

      NSLog(@"ROW:%@",log);
    log=@"";

    //For column check

    for (int i=0; i<ORDER; i++)
    {
        log=[log stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,",y]];
        if (![[_buttons1_25 objectAtIndex:y-1] isSelected])
        {
            col=FALSE;
            break;
        }
        y+=5;

        if (i+1==ORDER)
        {
            col=TRUE;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"COL:%@",log);
    log=@"";

    //For diagonal1 check

    if (y1==x1+1)
    {
        for (int i=0,j=1; i<ORDER; i++,j++)
        {
            log=[log stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,",ORDER*i+j]];
            if (![[_buttons1_25 objectAtIndex:ORDER*i+j-1] isSelected])
            {
                diag1=FALSE;
                break;
            }
            if (i+1==ORDER)
            {
                diag1=TRUE;
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"D1:%@",log);
    log=@"";

    //For diagonal2 check

    if (x1+1==ORDER-y1+1)
    {

        for (int i=0,j=5; i<ORDER; i++,j--)
        {
            log=[log stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,",ORDER*i+j]];
            if (![[_buttons1_25 objectAtIndex:ORDER*i+j-1] isSelected])
            {
                diag2=FALSE;
                break;
            }
            if (i+1==ORDER)
            {
                diag2=TRUE;
            }
        }
    }

     NSLog(@"D2:%@",log);
    log=@"";

    //Same loops above repeated only this time we set the button colors

    x=x1;
    y=y1;

    if (row)
    {

        for (int i=ORDER*x+1; i<=ORDER*x+ORDER; i++)
        {
            UIButton *cell=[_buttons1_25 objectAtIndex:i-1];
            [cell setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:theme.multipleButton] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [cell setTitleColor:theme.multipleButtonTitleColor forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        }
    }


    if (col)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<ORDER; i++)
        {
            UIButton *cell=[_buttons1_25 objectAtIndex:y-1];
            [cell setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:theme.multipleButton] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [cell setTitleColor:theme.multipleButtonTitleColor forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            y+=5;
        }
    }

    if (diag1)
    {
        for (int i=0,j=1; i<ORDER; i++,j++)
        {
            UIButton *cell=[_buttons1_25 objectAtIndex:ORDER*i+j-1];
            [cell setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:theme.multipleButton] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [cell setTitleColor:theme.multipleButtonTitleColor forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        }
    }

    if (diag2)
    {
        for (int i=0,j=5; i<ORDER; i++,j--)
        {
            UIButton *cell=[_buttons1_25 objectAtIndex:ORDER*i+j-1];
            [cell setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:theme.multipleButton] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [cell setTitleColor:theme.multipleButtonTitleColor forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's slightly hacky, but one solution is to assign each button a distinct prime number as a tag. Multiply the tag for each selected button together. Each row, column and diagonal will have a distinct prime product; you can store these in a constant array. Now, just check to see if each element of this array is a factor of the product; if it is, the corresponding row (column, diagonal) is "selected".

As an example, on a 3x3 grid, tag them as:

```
2  3   5
7  11  13
17 19  23
```

The row products are 30, 1001 and 7429. The columns are 238, 627 and 1495.

If numbers, 2, 3, 5, 11 and 19  are selected, that product is 6270. 30 is a factor of that, so the first row is selected. So is 627, so that column is selected as well.

If you use this solution, comment it well. It's not necessarily obvious. A somewhat more straightforward solution is to store a constant array indicating which sets of selected buttons form rows, columns and diagonals. Check to see if each element of this array is a subset of the currently selected button set. This is essentially the same solution (albeit slightly more code heavy), but has the advantage of being an obvious and maintainable solution.

Comment: How about powers of 2 rather than primes, and add them together rather than multiplying?  It's easier to OR things than to factorise them, and the OP only has 25 buttons so they're well within the size of an integer.

Comment: Powers of two work as well! Any object which can be reversibly combined will do fine.

Comment: Even so I would have to right 12 conditions for all rows, columns and diagonals, isnt it?

Comment: Well, you don't need 12 conditionals; one loop over an array with 12 "success" criteria in it will work fine.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I follow you correctly, can u update your code and show me what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert button's tag into (x,y):

```
const NSInteger rows = 5; // for you 5x5 format
const NSInteger x = tag % (rows - 1);
const NSInteger y = tag / (rows - 1);
```

And now, you can check rows and cols easy.
If `x` of selected buttons is equals – this is one row, and so on.

Comment: since i'm doing this on ios, i dont think i can set the button tag in (x,y) format, currently my button tag is set from 1 to 25.

Comment: Yeah, you need to set button's `tag` from 0 to 24. In you tap event handler use my sample code to convert your `sender.tag` value from (0..24) into `x`, `y` values.